# Wordpress-ob_start():failed to create buffer

Tags: wordpress, gzip

My website was built with wordpress and now I get the following error:

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  ob_start(): function '‘ob_gzhandler’' not
>   found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php on
>   line 15

And this is index.php:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg2H0.png)

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Content-Encoding header.

```
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
```